# getting Content Security Policy error after deploying jhipster Angular application on Heroku while accessing Marketo REST APIs

Tags: angular, spring, heroku, jhipster, marketo

I have created Angular based monolith application using jhipster. From Angular I made http calls to [Marketo REST APIs](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/asset-endpoint-reference/#!/Folders/getFolderUsingGET) and are working fine in my local.  I could able to generate access token then GET folders and Create folders.  Then I have deployed to heroku, (https://xxx123.herokuapp.com/), but there I am. getting below error,

```
Refused to connect to 'https://895-ufd-655.mktorest.com/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=xxx'

 because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `*.mktorest.com;` in  `application.yml` as shown. below it solves the issue

```
content-security-policy: "default-src 'self' *.mktorest.com;
```